# Error while loading excel file with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying yo load an excel file using Openpyxl in Python.

```
   from openpyxl import load_workbook 
    wb2 = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
    print wb2.get_sheet_names()
```

It just these three lines. and it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/excel1.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb2 = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 141, in load_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(f, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\zipfile.py", line 793, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\zipfile.py", line 835, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

This is exactly like their Documentation. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html
Is their any better package to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If this file does not exist at the desired location, try:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

# 1) create a workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb.save('my.xlsx')
del wb
# 2) build connection with the just created excel
book = load_workbook('my.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the file. When we saved the file externally it was prompting this error. easy fix is to make a try catch and if the it gives the error create a new file in the same name and save on the same place. But for appending with old data wont work in this case.

```
try:
    # this statement shall raise error for Badzip file
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path)
except:
    # try to create a new file and save at same path
    wb_obj = openpyxl.Workbook()
    wb_obj.save(path)
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path)
```

Answer (score -1):

xlsx files are zip archives. It looks like the file you're trying to open isn't. If you think this isn't the case please submit a but with a sample file.

Comment: I do not understand. what are you trying to say ?i just created a simple excel sheet with .xlsx extension

Comment: Please submit a bug report with the file. The error message is because there is a problem with the file.